# angular 2 - when to prefer component against module?

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-module

This seems really easy question but I can't find right answer to this question. AFAIK, module is preferred mostly when you're trying to lazy load something. Other than that, some says I should just wrap every component to module but I don't see any benefit of doing that. If something is module and is not either shared or core module, then it should be feature module which I don't know how I should really define its size.

Let's say I'm trying to create daterangepicker, I'll import single datepicker and add it twice in a component to make one "from"datepicker and another "to"datepicker. There, I have daterangepicker component but should I wrap this into module? If yes, what's the benefit of wrapping this into module? If no, then when can I turn something into feature module?

Comment: They are different concepts. Component or module are never interchangeable. Modules are to group components, directives, pipes, and services together to create a reusable feature. There is no benefit of wrapping a 3rd-party component into a module, there is only a benefit of wrapping your own components with all parts that are needed for this component to work (components, directives, pipes, and services).

Comment: Hi @GünterZöchbauer , thanks for the quick answer! So if I were not to reuse or lazy load such feature, then is there still benefit of grouping the stuffs to module? Again, if I were to have a component with input field, submit button, and importing that daterangepicker picker component to record schedule by using a service sending the data out to server; but will not reuse nor lazy load, what benefits can I get by wrapping these into module?

Comment: It allows you to create easy to reuse building blocks. Add the module to `imports: [...]` of another module and it's functionality can be used. 
This way you keep your code modular and maintainable.